# Path completion with fzf from absolute path

Tags: fzf

I'm confused on how to make use of path completion with fzf inside vim. I have it working with:

```
inoremap <expr> <c-x><c-f> fzf#vim#complete#path('rg --files')
```

This works fine when the path is relative path but I can't seem to make it useful when starting from the root directory of a very large tree. And if I type in something like:

`/User<c-x><c-f>`

It shows me a ton of files that begin with `/Volumes` which is clearly what I don't want. And it doesn't seem to work with any kind of tab completion either.

Can someone clue me in on how to best use fzf with path completion?

Seems almost useless. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting; I would have left the default file completion alone, since it handles absolute paths (and relative paths) perfectly. It’s just not “fuzzy”

Comment: Always have to keep learning and trying new things and experimenting. Fzf is pretty much a godsend in all other regards. I'm not sure if I'm using it right.